# PHP / MySQL search with foreign languages

Tags: php, sql

I have some texts in a mysql database, that are in several languages, including portuguese and russian, and have a lot of special characters, like á, à, ç, ã.
Is there a way for me to create a search function, that is able to search using the following wildcards:

`smil?` - finds: smile, but not smiling - the `'?'` represents one character. It can be used in the begining or in the end of the search term;
`smil*` - finds: simle, smiling, etc - the `'*'` represents any number of characters. It can be used in the begining or in the end of the search term;
`real |AND| madrid` - returns the records that contain both words;
`real |OR| madrid` - returns the records that contain at least one of the words;
`real |NOT| madrid` - returns the records that contain only real, but not madrid;
"real madrid" - returns the records that contain the exact expression;

I would also like to use multiple situations, like:

```
rea? |AND| madr* |AND| "manchester united"
```

One other problem is with the special characters. `re*` should also return reál, real, reãl...

And another situation is, if I search for `test`, it should find: tést, têst, etc...

Is this possible to accomplish? Can someone point me on the right direction?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Where exactly is your problem. If you use a common charset like UTF-8, at least php and the database should not be the showstoper.

Comment: what's wrong with: `SELECT * FROM something WHERE somethingElse LIKE "%rea%" ORDER BY somethingEvenElseier LIMIT 1000;` ?

Comment: I was just trying to place my doubt in context. My main issue is with the search returning variations with special characters, like when I search toto, it returns tótó, tõtó, tötô, etc. I can't find how to do that. Also, the database tables are InnoDB, forgot to mention that... This %rea% also returns areal, when I only what to search for rea*.

Comment: @ZlatanO. I think this is wrong that this will return "real madrid", "real estate", "korea", "chris rea", "tread" and many others.

Comment: @Voitcus, yes, but it's up to a person to filter response results from a given search query :)